# Can the C# compiler distinguish between I/O bound and computational tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Consider a snippet of code such as this:

```
public async Task<Bitmap> DownloadDataAndRenderImageAsync(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var imageData = await DownloadImageDataAsync(cancellationToken);
    return await RenderAsync(imageData, cancellationToken);
}
```

The first of the steps in this method is I/O bound work where as the second, computational.

When we rely on the compiler to generate the right task-based code for this asynchronous operation, what does the compiler do?

Specifically, does it know that the first one is I/O bound so it must use the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` class so that there is no affinity between a thread and the task, and that for the second one, it can use any of the methods such as `Run` or `StartNew` or `Start` to schedule the task on a thread-pool thread?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No. In the example you've given, the compiler will only use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (indirectly) for the overall asynchronous operation (`DownloadDataAndRenderImageAsync`). It's up to the two methods that are called to decide how they're going to return the relevant task.

Maybe `DownloadImageDataAsync` is itself an `async` method which delegates down to some more async I/O. Maybe `RenderAsync` calls `Task.Run`. Those are both implementation details that the compiler doesn't care about *at all* when compiling `DownloadDataAndRenderImageAsync`.

Answer (score 34):

> When we rely on the compiler to generate the right task-based code for this asynchronous operation, what does the compiler do?

In the example you give the compiler knows that DownloadImageDataAsync and RenderAsync are methods that return awaitables. Awaitables are objects that can be (1) queried for completion, and (2) have a continuation signed up to their completion.  The compiler generates code that detects whether the returned awaitables are completed, and if they are not, signs up the remainder of the method as the completion of the awaitable.

> Specifically, does it know that the first one is I/O bound

Nope. It knows that it returns something awaitable.

> so it must use the TaskCompletionSource class so that there is no affinity between a thread and the task

If you care about the details of the completion logic, you're responsible for ensuring that the context in which the await happens is the right context. If you don't care, you'll get an appropriate default context.

> and that for the second one, it can use any of the methods such as Run or StartNew or Start to schedule the task on a thread-pool thread?

The compiler doesn't do any such thing. The compiler generates code that checks whether the returned awaitable is complete, and if not, signs up the completion of the awaitable. How that awaitable works is the responsibility of the callee, not the compiler!

Answer (score 16):

Neither the compiler not the runtime know that. In fact the whole term "IO bound" is vaguely defined. Is any OS call an IO?! Is sleeping or timing an IO?!

If you have to ask this question you might have some misconceptions around tasks because it normally is not necessary to know this.

Maybe it's the common error to think that await starts a task? It waits for an existing task to complete. `DownloadImageDataAsync` and `RenderAsync` decide how and when to complete that task. So they decide whether to use the CPU or perform IO.

When `DownloadImageDataAsync` and `RenderAsync` hand you a task you don't know what's inside and you don't need to know.

Comment: `Is any OS call an IO?! Is sleeping or timing an IO?!` Yes. Functions which have [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) are not [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and it seems for the intents and purposes of the question that IO is being conflated with purity.

Comment: @cat pure != no IO. Even if IO was precisely defined, and your definition is not universally accepted, the question is still: What is IO-**bound**? Nothing is 100% IO. Such a vague term.

Comment: @usr: And, of course, once you *do* define it rigorously enough that the question starts to make sense, the answer is: deciding that question is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. (Which is pretty much the answer to *all* questions of the form "can the compiler distinguish XYZ".)